# Microsoft Access - Use one report Template for multiple Queries?

Tags: ms-access, reporting

I have an Access DB, and I have about 26 queries that have to be run in order to produce compliance reports. What I am wondering, is it possible to format the Form that's being used by the end user, in such a way as to push through the queries I want them to select. I know it can be done if I use dynamic queries, but there were problems with the dynamic queries that my limited skills were unable to overcome, so I built new, better queries, that do the job they are supposed to with no errors. The problem is I don't want to have to build a new report for each query, but rather have the form feed the query directly to the same report template, but with each query being selected by a different button.

I was certain I could do it via embedded macros, but can't seem to find a way to do that.

Comment: Pass your query name as the `OpenArgs` when you `DoCmd.RunReport.`  In the `Report.Open` event, set the `RecordSource` property to the `OpenArgs` value.  See also https://www.comeausoftware.com/2019/01/dynamic-report-recordsource-access/

Comment: Why do you have 26 queries with same structure for one report object? Instead of building multiple queries, likely just need to apply filter criteria to report.

Comment: Compliance expiration dates are not all the same, I could pull one big query, get all the start dates, filter down to the requested compliance issue on each button, then calculate the expiration date by pulling from another table, I think. But I've never done filtering before. So here's something new.

Comment: I am fairly certain you have done filtering - in query with static parameters. My suggestion is to dynamically build filter criteria in VBA procedure and apply to report when it opens using WHERE CONDITION argument of OpenReport method.

Comment: I would add to @RobertHarvey 's answer, confirm that the report has boxes and layouts which match the tables and fields of your underlying queries.

Comment: Could you all *PLEASE* put your answer in the Answer form and mark a question answered?

Comment: I concur with @June7.  Your problem can most likely be solved with a WHERE clause in the OpenReport call.

Comment: @Eckman: To be fair, this can all be found in the Microsoft documentation and the linked article above.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd.openreport